# Extends ViewGroup

Tags: android, android-layout

```
public SomeClass(Context context, SomeType some_arg) {
         super(context);
         LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(
                  Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_layout_with_button, this, true);
        m_button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.mButton);
        m_textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mTextView);
        m_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                //TODO
                }
            });
    }
```

In Activity, in onCreate(...) I wrote

```
this.setContentView(new SomeClass(getApplicationContext(),arg));
```

SomeClass extends LinearLayout, some_layout_with_button.xml is correct 
But on emulator's display  - nothing. Why?

UPD:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="20px">
        <Button android:id="@+id/mButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="BT" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/mTextView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="16px"
                />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RadioGroup android:id="@+id/mRadioGroup"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/mRadioButton1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="60px"
                    android:text="Text1"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/mRadioButton2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="60px"
                    android:text="Text2"/>
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you call `super.onCreate()`?

Comment: yes, sure, I called super.onCreate(...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a few calls to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View,%20int) are missing from your constructor code

Comment: don't understand,were you telling about what I should in SomeClass constructor call addView(...)? Why? I added all necessary elements in xml file.

Comment: WEll, SomeClass is basically a ViewGroup. How are the two Views (textview and button) getting their parent set as your SomeClass instance ?

Comment: Ok, I created xml file (added to question), after I added this layout to my View(SomeClass) , what should I do now?

Comment: Let me see if I get what you are after. Are you trying to link that posted XML content to SomeClass ?

Comment: if that is the case, then change the outermost element in XML from LienearLayout to your.package.Someclass (preserving other parameters), add it an 'android:id' parameter (let's say 'someId') and in the Activity's onCreate just call setContentView(findViewById(R.layout.someId)); -written from memory. Going to dinner now

Comment: No, I'm going to add this View(SomeClass) into Activity's ViewGroup from a code.
Bon appetit =)